# Multiple Line plot from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, plot, line

from a dataframe I need to plot by month the count of events to know which ones are more likely to happen in a given month. I don know how to use the column Count.

```
df["MONTH"]= pd.to_datetime(df["BEGIN_DATE_TIME"], format = "%m/%d/%Y").dt.month
montly_events =df.groupby(["EVENT_TYPE", "MONTH"]).size().astype(int)
montly_events2 = montly_events.to_frame(name = "Count").reset_index()

plt.figure(figsize =(15,3))
sns.lineplot(x="MONTH", y="EVENT_TYPE", palette="ch:.25", data=df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, count is another column in your df, try to make that as a 'y', the one that you have included here as screenshot

Try

```
sns.lineplot(x="MONTH", y="count", palette="ch:.25", data=df)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working  I will try ggplot   sns.lineplot(x="MONTH", y="Count", palette="ch:.25", data=df)   ValueError: Could not interpret value `Count` for parameter `y`

Comment: does your df has 'Count' as a column?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I found using a barplot:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(montly_ev2, row="EVENT_TYPE", hue="MONTH",palette="Set3", height=4, aspect=2)

g.map(sns.barplot, 'MONTH', 'Count', order=hours)
```